# Checking for presence of elements using Protractor and chai as promised

Tags: javascript, protractor, chai, chai-as-promised

I am having trouble testing for the absence of elements in my node.js app.

I have an `enterBtn` button that, when clicked, it displays `resultsTable` and a `clearBtn`. The `enterBtn` is always present.

I am trying to test that the `resultsTable` disappears when I click the `clearBtn` and I am having trouble with that.

```
'use strict';

const chai = require('chai');
chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
chai.should();
const expect = chai.expect;

require('./lib/test-helper');

const until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

describe('My App', function() {
    it('should clear resultsTable clearBtn is clicked', function(){
        var resultsTable = element(by.id('results-table'));
        clearBtn.click();

        expect(resultsTable.isPresent()).to.eventually.be.false;
      }); 
});
```

I also tried to do this:

```
resultsTable.isPresent().then(function(bln) {
     expect(bln).to.equal(false);
});
```

And that didn't work either:

```
"Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test."
```

But if I try to test for the presence of the `enterBtn`, which is always present, using the code below, it works.

```
var enterBtn = element(by.id('enter'));
expect(enterBtn.isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true;
```

I'm not sure what's going on...

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the full test?

Comment: Check this answer out for Mocha. Important to check which dependencies you use / config setup. Once that's verified, include more information about what kind of app you are testing and the protractor config. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839202/protractormocha-fails-suite-with-typeerror-before-browser-loads-sut/42853148#42853148

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I added more details, I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Shouldn't you put the line that goes `var resultsTable = element(by.id('results-table'));` _after_ the call to `click()`?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Actually, on my test script, I defined a bunch of variables right below the describe. I defined the enter button there as well and that works in the positive cases. It's only where I am expecting a false scenario that doesn't work o.O

Comment: Yeah but like you said, the `enterBtn` doesn't really change. Can you try what I suggested?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I tried it, same error :(

Comment: `isPresent` checks if an element is in the DOM, `isDisplayed` checks if an element is present in the DOM *AND* is also visible. What should happen when you click on the button, should the table be hidden? If so, you should use `isDisplayed`

Comment: @wswebcreation I tried using isDisplayed and get the same error... :/

Comment: Can you give more info like a HTML example

Comment: So once I click clearBtn, the results-table disappears from the DOM. This is what I tried to do as you suggested: expect(resultsTable.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.false;

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the clearBtn, does the element disappear immediately?
If no, try putting a sleep after clearBtn.click() to ensure that object will be gone before expect.

You can also simplify your expect by using
expect(resultsTable.isPresent()).toBe(false)

```
describe('My App', function() {
    it('should clear resultsTable clearBtn is clicked', function(){
        var resultsTable = element(by.id('results-table'));
        clearBtn.click();
        browser.sleep(2000);
        resultsTable.isPresent().then(function(bln) {
            expect(bln).toBe(false);
        });
    }); 
});
```

If object might take more than 2 seconds, you cna try using this recursive function https://stackoverflow.com/a/43679616/7761311