# Protractor, checking if current Url is equal to string url

Tags: javascript, url, browser, protractor, chai

I'm trying to check if the current url of the page after click on submit button is changed to the right url.
I tried to do it in many ways that i found on web, but nothing is worked. Sometimes the problem is that it can't be possible to doing equality for "url object" and "string", sometimes something else. One thing is surely, the error when i launch the test. Can you help me? Thank you.

Here my stepdefinition.js

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.equal("https://myurl.com/eng/homepage.html");
```

Here my error:

```
E/launcher - expected { Object (flow_, stack_, ...) } to equal 'https://myurl.com/eng/homepage.html'
```

[15:34:28] E/launcher - AssertionError: expected { Object (flow_, stack_, ...) } to equal 'https://myurl.com/eng/homepage.html'

Comment: Given the error message.

Comment: I added it on the question

Comment: Adding this here. I answered a similar question a while ago about Chai with TypeScript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839202/protractormocha-fails-suite-with-typeerror-before-browser-loads-sut/42853148#42853148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

browser.getCurrentUrl() returns a promise. You'll need to resolve it using .then() as shown below :

**Option 1)** Only use `chai`

```
// protractor conf.js
onPrepare: function() {
    var chai = require('chai'),
        chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    global.expect = chai.expect;
    // make `expect`as global, so you can use it anywhere is your code
}

browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(currentUrl){
  expect(currentUrl).to.equal("https://myurl.com/eng/homepage.html");
})
```

**Option 2)**  Use `chai` and `chai-as-promised` together:

```
// protractor conf.js
onPrepare: function() {
    var chai = require('chai'),
        chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    global.expect = chai.expect;
    // make `expect`as global, so you can use it anywhere is your code
}

expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually
      .equal("https://myurl.com/eng/homepage.html");
```

Comment: Avinashs15 thank you for your reply. Even in this case it gives me back an error:
E/launcher - Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined
[16:42:38] E/launcher - TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined

This error is reffered to the line: "currentUrl.to.equal("https://myurl.com/eng/homepage.html");" where currentUrl is undefined

Comment: @Spicchio try using an `expect(currentUrl).to.equal('whatever url you're using')`;

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("https://myurl.com/eng/homepage.html");
```

Comment: Hi @BlueScoreMan thank u for ur reply. Unfortunately i have this message error:
E/launcher - Invalid Chai property: toEqual. Did you mean "equal"?
[16:02:59] E/launcher - Error: Invalid Chai property: toEqual. Did you mean "equal"?

Comment: He used Jasmine build-in assertion API (which require write test case by Jamsine). But from your given code, seems you use `chai` as assertion libaray.